# How do I edit a library that I created?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a library of functions that i use over and over. I'm using in my spreadsheet scripts. Now i want to add more functions to the library but can't figure out how to open the library source file.

here is what I have already tried:
- file > open (no dice)
- resources > libraries > click on library name (opens documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your post, you cannot find the original library Apps Script file.

In the Included Libraries window, get the file title (e.g. Forward by Label)
[image]

Then do a search in Google Drive.  If you're using the New Drive, the Advanced Search string would look like this:  ***app:"Google Apps Script" title:"Forward by Label"***

Comment: Hi thanks for this but i'm unable to find the library using this method.

Comment: @Cyrus - your right, I used your method in a less "error prone" way that avoids typos  ;-)  btw, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Sergeinsas thank you.  Mike, are you using the old or new Drive interface?  If the old, try the new, for the app: search functionality.  Also, if the library has a unique function name, you could search on that function name.  Are you sure three library you are looking for is yours?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your original script and get the project key by going to file > project properties. Then open the new script and click resources > libraries and paste in the key.

[image]

You'll also need to save a new version and select that version to access any new changes you make.

Comment: This is a good explanation of how to add a library. But the issue is opening a library that I've already added to the script.

Answer (score 0):

This small script will find it if you know the title of your library *(and you know it using the tip given in the other answer :-)* (which btw was right, you can use advanced search in the Drive Ui to perform such a search..., this is only a way to simplify the process).

The title to search for is also the word combination you use to use your library, you'll find it in all the other scripts that use that library.

```
function findLibrary() {
  var scriptUrl = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "LibraryTitle"').next().getUrl();
  Logger.log(scriptUrl);
}
```

Open the logger and copy the url... that's it !

Note : use this code in **any** script editor session, it will simply ask for authorization for DriveApp. [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String)).

Comment: thanks - i understand that searching should work. but the search does not return anything. also i improved this  the script a little, function findLibrary() {
 var files = DriveApp.searchFiles ('title contains "CSValidate"');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   Logger.log(file.getUrl());
 }
}

Comment: and it worked like that ? what were the returned values and, most important, what was the first returned value ? My script assumes the first result is OK ;-)

Comment: yeah, right...i guess it would work if there was a value returned. the problem is there is no results:(   how can this library exist (it works perfectly when it's called) but is not findable.

Comment: are you sure about exact spelling ?

Comment: yeah i am positive about the spelling.

Comment: Ok i found a way to do it. I click the name in resources window. This opens the link to documentation. I took the ID out of the documentation URL and pasted it into the URL as follows: https://script.google.com/a/credsimple.com/macros/d/<ID-from-documentation-link>/edit

Comment: nice ! make it an answer and accept it ;-) (not sure I understand why it didn't work for you the other way though... strange...) but the good thing is that you found a solution !!